# IIS 8.5: Virtual Account for App Pool (IIS AppPool\{Application Pool Name} is not available

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012, application-pool, windows-server-2012-r2, iis-8.5

I am running IIS 8.5 on a Windows 2012 R2 Core box.  I created a new application pool called "MyNewAppPool".  I have a website instance, called "MyNewWebsite.com" running in the "MyNewAppPool" application pool.  The Identity used for "MyNewAppPool" is "ApplicationPoolIdentity".

It is my understanding that I can assign security permissions for application pools in IIS 8.5 by using the auto-generated local virtual accounts, which will be named "IIS AppPool\{Application Pool Name}".

So, in Windows Explorer on the "MyNewWebsite.com" directory, I should be able to assign read/write permissions for the virtual user account "IIS AppPool\MyNewAppPool".  I cannot find this user account to assign any permissions to.  I am searching the local computer location and not the whole domain.  I **can** find the "IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool" account, however I don't want to run MyNewWebsite.com under the DefaultAppPPool, I want to run it under the MyNewAppPool application pool.

Can anyone please tell me why I don't can't find the auto-generated virtual account for MyNewAppPool?

Answer (score 14):

You won't ever find the synthesised application pool identity in the permissions search dialogue. Just type in the name of the pool identity like this:

**Via GUI:**

[image]

The click the *Check Names* button:

[image]

**Via Command Line:**

Alternatively you can use `ICACLS` from an administrator command line/Powershell:

```
icacls c:\wwwroot\mysite /grant "IIS AppPool\MyNewAppPool":(CI)(OI)(M)
```

Comment: I tried exactly this.  I still cannot get the application pool name to resolve. 

I had this issue on a dev server, and then for an unknown reason the issue went away.  Now I'm setting up a QA server I'm experiencing the same problem again.

Comment: @KPhillipson I've seen that before on original Windows 2008 Server and Windows 2008R2 (pre-service pack) and it was mighty bloody annoying. Have a look at my update, it should work with `ICACLS` from the command line.

Comment: @Kev, nope.  `No mapping between account names and security IDs was done.
Successfully processed 0 files; Failed processing 1 files`

Comment: @BrainSlugs83 - what OS, have you got all the latest service packs/updates? Are you sure you're running powershell/command prompt as Administrator? Have you spaces in the path you're granting permissions to? If so wrap in double quotes.....you've not provided much info to go on, I don't normally complain but the DV seems a wee bit unfair as it's not an egregiously incorrect answer. Sounds more like your environment is to blame than the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Above answer works great, just remember to use the server's name rather than the domain name. I got hung up for a bit trying to figure out why it wasn't resolving:
[image]

Comment: OP does mention in the question *"I am searching the local computer location and not the whole domain."*

Comment: Nope.  Server is not domain joined; local machine name is populated there by default.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in Server 2012 -- for whatever reason it was not creating the virtual accounts (or they were not available for use). -- I believe it's related to the `AppHostSvc` or the `NetMan` service not running. -- Ultimately, I took a shotgun approach to fixing it (not recommended, you should try to do as little as possible for a production environment, but this PowerShell might get you out of a pinch in your dev. environment):

```
#Requires -Version 4
#Requires -RunAsAdministrator

#######################################

$DebugPreference = "SilentlyContinue";
$VerbosePreference = "SilentlyContinue";
$WarningPreference = "Continue";
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop";
Set-PSDebug -Strict;
Set-StrictMode -Version 3;

#######################################

Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online `
    | where { $_.FeatureName -ilike "*IIS*" -and $_.State -eq "Disabled" } `
    | % { Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName $_.FeatureName -All };

iisreset

Get-Service | ? { $_.ServiceName -eq "W3SVC" } | Start-Service;
Get-Service | ? { $_.ServiceName -eq "W3SVC" } | Set-Service -StartupType Automatic;

Get-Service | ? { $_.ServiceName -eq "WMSvc" } | Start-Service;
Get-Service | ? { $_.ServiceName -eq "WMSVC" } | Set-Service -StartupType Automatic;

Get-Service | ? { $_.ServiceName -eq "AppHostSvc" } | Start-Service;
Get-Service | ? { $_.ServiceName -eq "AppHostSvc" } | Set-Service -StartupType Automatic;

Get-Service | ? { $_.ServiceName -eq "Netman" } | Start-Service;
Get-Service | ? { $_.ServiceName -eq "Netman" } | Set-Service -StartupType Automatic;

iisreset
```